# PHP XML Request

Tags: php, xml

I have a list of tickets provided in an XML file I load via:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
```

The tickets having a record named  containing two fields as below:

```
<tickets>
  <ticket>
    <custom-fields>
      <custom-field type="List" name="public" id="1392571">Public</custom-field>
      <custom-field type="List" name="Typ" id="1150963">Change Request</custom-field>
    </custom-fields>
  </ticket>
  <ticket>
    <custom-fields>
      <custom-field type="List" name="public" id="1392571">Non-Public</custom-field>
      <custom-field type="List" name="Typ" id="1150963">Change Request</custom-field>
    </custom-fields>
  </ticket>
</tickets>
```

Now, I want to display only Public tickets. But I wnat to display the Type of the ticket.

So I need to check

1. if the first custom-field has attribute name="public" and value "Public"
2. if so, then show the VALUE from the sibling field with attribute name="Typ"

What I already can check is the first part as:

```
if($ticket->{'custom-fields'}[0]->{'custom-field'}[0]) == "PUBLIC"){
  //now populate the Value from the second field
}
```

Q: How can I extract the value from the sibling now?

Or better. Is it possible to get the value of a field having a special atrribute with value? Liek I do in XPATH with:

```
/tickets/ticket/custom-fields/custom-field[@name="public"]/../custom-field[@name="Typ"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this entirely with an XPath query: `'/tickets/ticket/custom-fields[custom-field="Public"]/custom-field[@name="Typ"]'`:

Full example:

```
$xmlString = '
<tickets>
  <ticket>
    <custom-fields>
      <custom-field type="List" name="public" id="1392571">Public</custom-field>
      <custom-field type="List" name="Typ" id="1150963">Change Request (public)</custom-field>
    </custom-fields>
  </ticket>
  <ticket>
    <custom-fields>
      <custom-field type="List" name="public" id="1392571">Non-Public</custom-field>
      <custom-field type="List" name="Typ" id="1150963">Change Request (non-public)</custom-field>
    </custom-fields>
  </ticket>
</tickets>';

$xmlDoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

$output = $xmlDoc->xpath('/tickets/ticket/custom-fields[custom-field="Public"]/*[@name="public"]/../custom-field[@name="Typ"]');
```

Gives

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "List"
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "Typ"
      ["id"]=>
      string(7) "1150963"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Change Request (public)"
  }
}
```

*Tested on PHP 7.2*